# MacVim's Python processes populate Activity Monitor and take 99% CPU

Tags: macos, memory, python, activity-monitor

Every time I open up MacVim, a Python process starts up. After exiting the program, they remain running. Opening up MacVim a second time will produce another Python process.

What do I do to stop this?

[image]

Below is my .vimrc

```
inoremap jk <Esc>

set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required
set guifont=Iosevka-Custom-Extended:h21
set number
set laststatus=2 
set tabstop=5
set shiftwidth=5
set expandtab
set updatetime=1000
syntax on 

let g:polyglot_disabled = ['markdown']

let g:ycm_clangd_binary_path = "/usr/local//Cellar/llvm/11.0.0/bin/clangd"

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'severin-lemaignan/vim-minimap'
"Plugin 'numirias/semshi'
Plugin 'challenger-deep-theme/vim', {'name': 'challenger-deep-theme'}
Plugin 'NLKNguyen/papercolor-theme'
Plugin 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plugin 'python-mode/python-mode'
"Plugin 'octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight'
Plugin 'dstein64/vim-win'
Plugin 'sjl/badwolf'
Plugin 'agude/vim-eldar'
Plugin 'bignimbus/pop-punk.vim'
Plugin 'jeaye/color_coded'
"Plugin 'bfrg/vim-cpp-modern'
Plugin 'davits/YouCompleteMe'
"Plugin 'lifepillar/vim-solarized8'
Plugin 'vim-jp/vim-cpp'
Plugin 'uiiaoo/java-syntax.vim'

call vundle#end()            " required

filetype plugin indent on    " require
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on'

let g:pymode_run = 1
let g:pymode_run_bind = '<leader>r'

syntax on 
let g:cpp_member_variable_highlight = 1
let g:cpp_class_decl_highlight = 1

let g:color_coded_enabled = 1

" autocmd FileType python setlocal foldmethod=expr foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'^\\s*#'
autocmd Filetype java set makeprg=java\ %

set t_Co=256   " This is may or may not needed.

"set background=dark
"colorscheme PaperColor

autocmd BufEnter __run__,__doc__ :wincmd L

"autocmd VimEnter * RltvNmbrd

set linespace=6

let g:cpp_attributes_highlight = 1
let g:cpp_member_highlight = 1
let g:cpp_simple_highlight = 1

let java_highlight_functions = 1
" let java_highlight_all = 1
" If you are trying this at runtime, you need to reload the syntax file
set filetype=java

" Some more highlights, in addition to those suggested by cmcginty
highlight link javaScopeDecl Statement
" highlight link javaType Type
highlight link javaDocTags PreProc


" FDF9F0

"if has('syntax')
"    let g:eldar_green   = "#FDF9F0"     "F6CD83" 
"    let g:eldar_yellow  = "#EC7677"
"    let g:eldar_cyan    = "#3E7A9A"
"    let g:eldar_red     = "#F6CD83"
"    let g:eldar_blue    = "#FFCD59"

"    syntax enable             " Turn on syntax highlighting
"    silent! colorscheme eldar " Custom color scheme
"endif

"let g:eldar_text        = "#5BC0B2"  "#60C1B6"  "#82DCFF" "#4EB0CC
"let g:eldar_background  = "#000000"  "180F0D"    "1E120F"  "262626"  "#1F0B15"  "#151515" "#191919"

"hi Member " Any non-static member variable
"hi Variable " Any non-member variable
"hi Namespace
"hi EnumConstant

" Add a hook to patch the colorscheme
"function! FixColorscheme()
"  hi Member guifg='.s:cyan .' guibg='.s:darkgrey .' gui=italic
"  hi Variable guifg='.s:light_grey_blue .' guibg='.s:darkgrey .' gui=none
"  hi Namespace guifg='.s:red .' guibg='.s:darkgrey .' gui=none
"  hi EnumConstant guifg='.s:lightgreen .' guibg='.s:darkgrey .' gui=none
"endfunction

"augroup fix_colorscheme
"  au!
"  au ColorScheme * call FixColorscheme()
"augroup END

let g:twilighted_background  = "#FFFFFF"
colorscheme twilighted

highlight LineNr term=bold cterm=NONE ctermfg=DarkGrey ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=DarkGrey guibg=NONE

set guioptions=
set wrap!

set filetype=java
```

Comment: A program calls Python subprocesses. This is the normal way a Python program ruins on multiple CPUs. To see the controlling program on Activity Monitor choose View and from that menu All Processes, Hierarchy

Comment: What if it is launchd? Or the system itself?

Comment: Have you tried the Activity Monitor view I suggested?

Comment: What does the ".vimrc" file in your home directory have in it?

Comment: Use something else instead of macvim?

Comment: I've posted my .vimrc @negacao

Comment: I suggest commenting out plugin line for YouCompleteMe, then close and reopen MacVim to see if that resolves your issue. I know that YouCompleteMe can be fairly CPU intensive, and it written in python. So a followup question: if you open up MacVim and wait 5-10 minutes, does the CPU use go down?

Comment: No. The computer eventually shuts down. I think it runs out of ram

Comment: Try commenting out all of the plugins. If that fixes the problem, re-enable them one by one to see which one is at fault.

Comment: What do the Python command lines say? You can list them in Terminal with `ps ax|grep Python`